# Как передать return в другую функцию python

Tags: python

у меня есть функция которая возвращает сумму двух цифр как передать это результат другой функции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def sum(x, y):
    return x + y


def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y


a = multiply(sum(2, 3), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func1(param)
    return 1

def func2(param)
    return 2


print(func1(func2(10)))
```

непонятно проблема - что мешает передать результат первой функции как параметр для второй?

Comment: Допустим func1 складывает 1+2 и хранит ответ 3,как передать без printa это значение к функции fun2 допустим что бы оно к тройку умножало  на 2  ,

Comment: @ИльмирСалехов не нужно хранить или принтить, возвращайте 1+2 с помощью return

Answer (score 0):

И еще один вариант:

```py
def fun1(x):
    return x

def fun2(x):
    return x


i = fun1(10) # i получит результат работы fun1
s = fun2(i) # в fun2 передаем i
print(s) # 10
```

Нужно ли хранить все в переменных или передать функцию параметром в функцию не создавая лишнего зависит от структуры программы.

Comment: Спасибо помогли !